# Is there a method for rearranging linked list in Java?

Tags: java, linked-list

Hi a Java newbie here.

I hava a linked list like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(5);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(2);
    
    System.out.println(list);

}
```

I am trying to find a way to find the max value in this linked list and cut the list from that max value until the end and paste it at the front of the linked list.
To clarify, for the example case, I would like the list to look something like this.

```
[5,4,2,1,2]
```

It would be appreciated if there would be any way of doing this.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: The easy way is to create a new linked list in the order you need using two loops, and finally just overwrite/assign your new list with the correct order `list = yourNewList;`

Comment: You first need to find the index of the max value in the list, call it `maxIdx`. You could then perform `list.addLast(list.removeFirst());` `maxIdx` times.

Comment: @RaffleBuffle - oh, that's much better than my answer. You should write it up.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've found that the 'max' element has index 'm'.

Copy the tail of the list starting at index 'm'.

Copy the head of the list stopping just before index 'm'.

```
List<Integer> temp = new LinkedList<>();

ListIterator<Integer> it1 = list.iterator(m);
while (it1.hasNext()) {
    temp.add(it1.next());
}

ListIterator<Integer> it2 = list.iterator(0);
while (it2.nextIndex() < m) {
    temp.add(it2.next());
}

list = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Collection` APIs don't support "cut and paste" operations<sup>1</sup>.  But the `List` API does support the notion of sublist views.  So you could do something like this:

1. Find the position of the max value
2. Create a sublist view from that position to the end of the list; e.g. `list.subList(pos, list.size())`
3. Copy the sublist view to a temporary list; e.g. `new ArrayList<>(sublist)`
4. Use `sublist.clear()` to remove all elements in the sublist view.
5. Insert the elements in the temporary list at the start of the original list; e.g. `list.addAll(0, tempList)`

Alternatively, you can build a new list as described in @iggy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68076624/139985) ... or using sublists if you want to avoid explicit loops.

---

<sup>1 - And the `LinkedList` API doesn't support "splicing" of lists.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

you can use stream Api in two steps :

1. Sort your LinkedList
2. Assign your linked list to the new sorted linked list

code :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
    linkedList.add(1);
    linkedList.add(2);
    linkedList.add(3);
    linkedList.add(4);
    linkedList.add(5);
    List<Integer> collect =linkedList.stream().sorted((a, b) -> b - a)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
    System.out.println(collect);;
}
```